# Sending JavaMail from Multiple Email Accounts

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a program where I have a number of users which each could be sending emails from different email accounts.

When I try to use JavaMail to send emails. They always get sent out by the account of the user who sent an email first.

```
user1 = new User("dummy-email@gmail.com", "dumpass12");
user2 = new User("second-dummy@gmail.com", "secondpass12");

user1.sendMail(toAddress, subject, body);
user2.sendMail(toAddress, subject, body);
```

Now when I do something like this, the second user will send a message but it will come from the SAME mailbox as user1 (i.e. both messages will come from dummy-email@gmail.com).

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening? Do I have to close the connection somehow? How can I send the two emails and have them come from the different accounts? Please help me.

Here is my code which actually sends the email connecting to the user's gmail account.

```
public void sendMail(String toAddress, String subject, String body){     
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            { return new PasswordAuthentication(getUsername(),getPassword());   }
        });     

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getUsername()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(body, "text/html");

            Transport.send(message);


            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }           
    }
```

Comment: Withoug seeing the relevant code (`getUsername()` &  the definition of the member that stores the user's address) nobody can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Replace Session.getDefaultInstance() with Session.getInstance().  To understand why, read the javadocs for those methods carefully.

Comment: Nothing beats having Bill Shannon answer your JavaMail questions.  (Hey, Bill, why is `InternetHeader` a final class? :) )

Comment: InternetHeader is final because InternetHeaders depends on the implementation details of InternetHeader, and since it's only used by the InternetHeaders class, that seemed reasonable.

Comment: By that logic, shouldn't *all* the classes be final?  If you're going to allow subclassing, having a few final classes makes things *very* difficult...

Comment: JavaMail doesn't depend on the implementation details of all the classes.  Many of them were designed for subclassing.